# How to get week number from date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get week number from date, if first date is Friday (interval week is Friday - Thursday)?

My query:

```
declare @week as int
set @week='04'

SELECT datepart(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,-5,Day))  Week,DAY

FROM [MyTable]
where datepart(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,-5,Day)) =@week
```

but the result is wrong.

how to get result like this:

[image]

Note: 29 Dec is in 2017

Comment: Do u have to generate this data?

Comment: How does your table look like?

Comment: yes @PawanKumar

Comment: like this @uzi

`Week 1 is (2017-12-29 to 2018-01-04)` etc

Comment: If your weeks are already separated like that, could you not just do `select [week], min([day]), max([day]) from mytable group by [week];`?

Comment: i just have date information only. i generate week from date.

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin, That is your expected output, is not it? And I asked about your existing table. How does data in that table look like? Is it a calendar table that keeps all days?

Comment: @uzi  in my table have all days, and i want to get week number from my table, and start date on week from friday.

Comment: @SeptianaFajrin, another question. How do you decide a week belongs to which month. If month can contain days from previous month, then week `26-Jan - 1-Feb` must belong to February, not January, is it? Or do you need to get result only for January?

Answer (score 0):

The first day of the week is based on the language settings of the server. The default setting is U.S. English 7 (Sunday). But you can easily change it by using [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql). Put this line at the top of your query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 5;
```